# How to specify form resize direction?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do i resize a borderless form?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: please add some code and let us see what you've done so far , so we can help you find a way through this problem .

Comment: Hint: the size property changes the extents, so what you are looking for is a way to change the top corner..

Comment: I think you mean form resizes from left to right, or top to down. So when you change width value forms left distance doesn't change only right distance changes. Is it true?

Answer (score 3):

You should change **left** value too while changing **width** and **top** value while changing **height**.

For example if you increase form size;

```
this.Left -= (changeWidth / 2);
this.Width += (changeWidth/ 2);
```

and

```
this.Top -= (changeHeight / 2);
this.Height += (changeHeight/ 2);
```